# ACTOR-platform REST Api?

Tags: actor, actor-platform

has anybody tried installing in digital ocean? what is the recommended specification and have they exposed any REST APIs? Their documentation is not yet complete and unable to judge how to close to they are production ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It installs on Ubuntu (no matter which cloud provider) [easily](https://github.com/actorapp/actor-bootstrap/tree/master/docs).

It is production ready, there was a [blog post](http://actorapp.ghost.io/platform-v1-0/) about it.
Documentation has been fulfilled to a 1.0 release too.